# Swift equivalent of Enum.ordinal() in Java

Tags: java, swift, enums

I was wondering if there is a Swift equivalent of Java's `Enum.ordinal()` method.

Comment: You are asking by .rawValue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `rawValue` to access the ordinal value of an enum marked with `Int`.

```
enum SomeEnum: Int {
    case first
    case second
    case third
    case fourth
}

print(SomeEnum.third.rawValue) //2
```

Comment: the 0,1, 2, 3 can be inferred